# Xpath - Select everything that is not the first p

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to select every node in an XHTML file that is not the first P tag. 
I'm modifying an existing stylesheet (h2d.xsl, for those who might look for it later) and currently the expression is:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="(body/*|body/text()|body/comment())[1]" mode="creating-content-before-section"/>
```

And essentially I'd like to modify to skip p[1]. I tried things like

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="(body/*[not(self::p[1])]|body/text()|body/comment())[1]" mode="creating-content-before-section"/>
```

But that does not work...

Any idea XSLT gurus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath should return any child of `body` element except the first `p` child element :

```
body/*[not(self::p and count(preceding-sibling::p)=0)]
```